# Unloading a Scala Object

Tags: android, scala

I made the mistake of writing a Scala program for Android and relying on Scala Objects. Well the singletons where really handy when writing a game but now when the game ends, class instances that are loaded by the main `Activity` are GC:d like they should be, but the Scala Objects seem to stay in memory. So when I restart the game, the objects are in an unknown state instead of just initializing like when first starting the game.

So what would be the correct way of "destroying" these objects? In other words, how to make sure that some destroy code is run when the Android `Activity` ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. You have to turn them into classes and instantiate one instance of each in your main `Game` object, or whatever it's called.

Objects are singletons for the entire duration of the *application* (until the JVM shuts down). That's why they should typically *not* contain anything mutable.